# How to use MVVM with any fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-mvvm

I have a **TabLayout** on a activity and when user clicks on any tab then a fragment is loaded. One of those fragments contains a **NavigationView** running inside a **DrawerLayout**. Now the problem is I have to implement **MVVM** for the whole app and so for the fragments too, I have done this for Activities but I am having trouble while implementing this for Fragments and how to deal with **ItemSelected** with MVVM and what to bind and how? I am unable to find a proper working sample of the same. Here's the code:

**MoreFragment.java**:

```
package com.abc.Fragments;

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.abc.MainActivity;
import com.abc.MoreFragmentViewModel;
import com.abc.R;

public class MoreFragment extends Fragment {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MoreFragmentViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container, false);
        return fragView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerLayout = getView().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);

    }
}
```

**fragment_more.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        app:navigationItemSelectedListener="@{()-> viewModel.onMyItemSelected()}"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MoreFragmentViewModel.java:**

package com.abc;

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import android.databinding.BaseObservable;

public class MoreFragmentViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public void onMyItemSelected(){
        System.out.print("Item Clicked");
    }
}
```

Please do any possible help.

Comment: As @Alex pointed out, you are not using [DataBinding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) properly.

Comment: Secondly, it is better to create _onMyItemSelected()_ function inside your activity and call _viewmodel.doStuffOnItemSelected()_ from there. The reason is that you can't *(you shouldn't)* modify UI from your viewmodel. Most of the time you would want to show/hide progress on click events which wouldn't be possible from viewmodel.

Comment: @ZohaibAmir Sorry but I am a newbie in mvvm so it will be a bit complex to do that for now as there are 2 more fragments and I don't know how to handle them from one activity. If you can tell me from some example that how will i handle multiple fragments from one activity then it will be very helpful.

Comment: There is an excellent example at official google docs: [Sharing Data between Fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)
  
To sum it up, when creating viewmodel inside fragment, you pass it activity(_getActivity()_ as context rather than fragment(_this_):  
  
``` 
ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);  
```  
  
Now both fragments will get same ViewModel instance. Remember, When you create ViewModel, it is separate for *each Context* which also means object is shared if context is same.

Comment: ok i will try to implement it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId(), container, false)
```

To inflate your layout.

And don't forget to add:

```
<data>
    <variable
            name="model"
            type="MoreFragmentViewModel"/>
</data>
```

To your fragment layout.

Comment: What to return from onCreateView(..) then?

Comment: Return root view of that ViewDataBinding

Comment: Is there any other change needed as I am getting this error: cannot generate view binders java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: It's probably happening because some imports aren't good, probably MoreFragmentViewModel as type of variable

Comment: as a type of variable?

Comment: This part: <variable
            name="model"
            type="MoreFragmentViewModel"/>

Comment: hmm i have already renamed it with the proper path with package, like com.abc.MoreFragmentViewModel

Comment: What I am returning from onCreateView is return binding.getRoot(); is it correct?

Comment: Yes, binding.getRoot();

Comment: ok, I commented all the changes you have suggested and the code is running fine without mvvm in fragment only when i use binding the errors comes out

Comment: Is there any problem with  app:navigationItemSelectedListener="@{()-> viewModel.onMyItemSelected()}" ?